# Text and Picture Spacing/Alignment Issues in Different Browsers

Tags: html, css, browser, alignment, spacing

I had a question about spacing and alignment between different browsers.  When I look at the following page (http://www.psych.utoronto.ca/users/ferber/people.php) on different browsers the spacing of the text and pictures is quite different (some browsers give much more space than others . . .I like how it looks on Safari best).

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue between browsers.  Below find the html code from the pages .php file and the general style sheet.  Please forgive my lack of ability in the coding department, I'm a relative novice to the the world of web design.

Thanks!

Justin

```
<?php

require("header.php");
?>


<h1>People</h1>
<h3><u>Victoria McLelland</u></h3>
<p><IMG style='border:2px solid #000000; margin: 0px 10px' src="pics/Victoria_crop.jpg" width="187" height="213" align=left>
  </TD>
  </IMG> I am a Post-Doctoral Fellow with Morgan Barense and Susanne Ferber. I completed my Ph.D. at the University of Auckland in New Zealand, where I examined the role of the hippocampus in encoding imagined episodic events into memory. Prior to this, I did my BA (Hons) in Psychology at the University of Guelph. I am generally interested in using fMRI to look at functional specialization within the medial temporal lobes. Outside the lab, I can usually be found spending time with my horse. <br /> Email: v.mclelland@gmail.com  </p>
<br>
<h3><u>Ryan Stevenson</u></h3>
<p><IMG style='border:2px solid #000000; margin: 0px 10px' src="pics/Ryan_crop.jpg" width="187" height="213" align=left>
  </TD>
  </IMG> I am a Banting Postdoctoral Fellow working with Morgan Barense and Susanne Ferber. I received my PhD from Indiana University before undertaking my first postdoc at Vanderbilt University. My research focuses on how we bind visual and auditory information from the environment into a unified percept. This research includes healthy individuals throughout the lifespan and clinical populations, specifically individuals with Autism. In my free time, I can usually be found reading, biking, traveling or cooking with friends. <br /> Email: ryan.andrew.stevenson@gmail.com  </p>
<br>
<h3><u>Kristin Wilson</u></h3>
<p><IMG style='border:2px solid #000000; margin: 0px 10px' src="pics/Kristin_crop.png" width="187" height="213" align=left>
  </TD>
  </IMG> I am a fourth year PhD student in the Ferber Lab, and completed my undergraduate degree at The University of Toronto.  I am interested in how individual differences in personality modulate attention and visual working memory, and the distinction between different modes of attention (such as selective and diffuse). I employ personality questionnaires to correlate different personality traits with attentional performance and elelectrophysiological marks of attention. In my spare time, I am a certified yoga teacher and enjoy playing guitar, hiking, and home rennovations.    <br /> Email: kwilson.psych@gmail.com  </p>
<br>
<h3><u>Sol Sun</u></h3>
<p><IMG style='border:2px solid #000000; margin: 0px 10px' src="pics/Sol_Sun_crop.jpg" width="187" height="213" align=left>
  </TD>
  </IMG> I am a first year PhD student in the Ferber Lab, also co-supervised by Jonathan Cant. I am interested in interactions between visual working memory and attention, and how these processes are engaged in high-level object perception and visual awareness. Some areas of current interest include: memory-guided visual search, studying conscious awareness using binocular rivalry / continuous flash suppression, the role of attentional scope in holistic perception of human faces and bodies, predicting strength of memory encoding using EEG oscillations.. <br /> Email: sol.sun@mail.utoronto.ca  </p>
<br>
<h3><u>Matt Lowe</u></h3>
<p><IMG style='border:2px solid #000000; margin: 0px 10px' src="pics/Matt_Lowe.jpg" width="187" height="213" align=left>
  </TD>
  </IMG> I am a first year PhD student in the Ferber Lab, also co-supervised by Jonathan Cant. My primary research investigates the representation of object and scene perception using psychophysical methods and functional neuroimaging. I am also interested in the nature of attention and awareness, and how individual differences in cognitive resources and capacity influence the way in which we perceive our immediate environment. Outside of the lab I enjoy traveling, with a special interest in mountaineering, but I can more often be found settled in at home with a good book. <br /> Email: mxlowe@gmail.com  </p>
 <br> 
<h3><u>Justin Ruppel</u></h3>
<p><IMG style='border:2px solid #000000; margin: 0px 10px' src="pics/Justin.jpg" width="187" height="213" align=left>
  </TD>
  </IMG> I am the lab manager and general trouble shooter for the Ferber Lab. I graduated from the University of Toronto with a degree in Human Biology and Psychology Research. After graduating, I spent a stint working at The Hospital for Sick Children and Mount Sinai Hospital as a research assistant for Dr. Joanne Rovet and Dr. Warren MacIsaac respectively. When I'm not untangling the functional threads of the human brain, I can be found at various speakeasies across Toronto playing folk, blues and jazz music. <br /> Email: ruppel@psych.utoronto.ca  </p>
  <br> 
<h3><u>Alumni</u></h3>
Maha Adamo, Ph.D.<br>
Hana Burianova, Ph.D.<br>
Steve Emrich, Ph.D.<br>Arin Klug, M.A.<br>Mark Shaw, M.A.<br>Stephenie Harrison<br>
Simona Mindy<br>
Linda Murray<br>
Raffles Cowan<br>
Felix Lee<br>
Lidia Liu<br>
Peter Lenkic<br>

  <?php
require("footer.php");

?>


/*Keeps vertical scrollbar present to prevent page shifting*/


html { min-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 1px; }

body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x:auto;
    font-size: 11.5pt;
}


#menu{
    width: 800px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding:0px;
}

#main {

    width: 800px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top:10px;
    text-align: left;
    padding:0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#innerLeft {

    float: left;
    width: 590px;
    height: 100%;
    background: white;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;

}

#innerRight {   

    float: left;
    width: 170px;
    height: 100%;
    background: white;
    border-left:thin solid grey;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 10pt;
    overflow: hidden;

}

ul#nav,ul#nav li{list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0}

ul#nav{margin-left: 0px;width:800px}

ul#nav li{float:left;margin-right: 3px;text-align: center;list-style: none outside none;position:relative;}

ul#nav a{float:left;width: 6em;padding: 5px 0;background: #B0C4DE;text-decoration:none;color: #000}

ul#nav a:hover{background: #E7F1F8;color: #000}

ul#nav li.activelink a,ul#nav li.activelink a:hover{background: #000000;color: #FFFFFF}

ul#list,ul#list li{list-style-type:none;margin-left:0px;margin-top:8px;padding:0}

ul#pub,ul#pub li{list-style-type:none;margin-left:0px;margin-top:12px;padding:0}  

/* ------- Dropdown Menu-------- */
#nav li:hover {background:#777;}

#nav ul {
position:absolute;
left:-999em;
top:1.9em;
list-style:none;
}

#nav li:hover ul {
display: inline-block;
left: -40px;
position: absolute;

}




/* ------- calendar specific styles -------- */

a.cal:link {text-decoration:underline;color:blue;display:block;width:100%;height:100%;background:white;}
a.cal:visited {text-decoration:underline;color:blue;display:block;width:100%;height:100%;background:white;}
a.cal:hover {text-decoration:underline;color:black;display:block;width:100%;height:100%;background:#DDDDDD;}
a.cal:active {text-decoration:underline;color:blue;display:block;width:100%;height:100%;background:white;}
```

Comment: Try using normalize http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ or any CSS reset, then re-style your layout. This way every browser will show you the same spacing for elements.

Answer (score 0):

well, the only way to do this is with a LOT of fine tuning. Sadly, due to the "Browser Wars", no browser renders alike, and most of them resist to adhere to "normal" CSS, so they start to use prefixes.

In this scenario, you'll need to do this:

1) Reset CSS (you can use any of the many CSS resets out there)

2) Include the HTML5 shim (hello IE!)

3) start using conditional CSS like this:

**Webkit: Safari, Opera and Chrome**

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){/*whatever*/}
```

**iPhone**

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {/*whatever*/}
```

**IE**

```
<!--[if IE]>
add styles here or style sheet
<![endif]-->
```

and of course you can use specific IE version targets, meaning you can change the IE version and use

```
less than IE9: <!--[if lt IE 9]>
less than or equal to IE9: <!--[if lte IE 9]>
greater than IE9:<!--[if gt IE 9]>
greater than or equal to IE9:<!--[if gte IE 9]>
```

4) Once you have all of that, let's go to the infamous vendor prefixes. Too long to list and changes every day, but in the meanwhile you can take a look at [Vendor Prefixed CSS Overview](http://peter.sh/experiments/vendor-prefixed-css-property-overview/). Basically, if you couldn't adjust using any of the methods above, it's because you probably need to use a vendor prefixed property.

Comment: Now, my insight is: does that additional pixel really, really, REALLY bothers you? Then use the methods above. Otherwise, do like 99% of developers do and unless it's too big to oversight, don't pay attention to it or you'll go crazy